# Cannot download Office 365 on macOS El-Capitan

Tags: macos, ms-office, software-update

I have a powerpoint assignment due for my class but although I purchased Microsoft 365, I can't download it to my computer because my Mac won't update to Mojave. I contacted Apple support and even got an external drive so I could do a time machine backup and upgrade. Did it but the computer is still not taking Mojave.

I would do the assignment on iPad but narrations apparently are only available on Android devices. So, I'm back to square 1 trying to gain access/functionality from the 365 I purchased on my Mac. Apple Support said, it might be a hardware issue since I was practicing scripts on the terminal last year. Any thoughts? I have a week, so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your current macOS version on which office won't run? Also, would online apps of MS helpful for you?

Comment: OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6 & I have access to MS 365 on my student website, but the narrations I am supposed to include w/ the PP presentation are not an available feature. Do you have any other suggestions for accessing MS online? Do you think I can access through MS since I bought the download? Also, thank you so much for responding to my request for assistance; and so quickly. Truly appreciate it!

Comment: What are the narrations you're talking about? The lectures you speak with the slides? I don't know if that can be done on Office suit apps. You can make videos ? Also, I am not very involved with MS products. you can contact their support, or wait for someone else to drop in. (notify me by @ankii )

Comment: Hi Anki,I apologize for responding so late (I've been doing homework all day) um but yea you're exactly right, I need to insert narrations of the subject matter on each slide. I thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't download it to my computer..

[App Store page](https://apps.apple.com/in/app-bundle/microsoft-office-365/id1450038993?mt=12) says OS X 10.6.6 or later is required.

**After** **sign-in**, https://portal.office.com/account#installs you'll see  two different links for Office download. One for *MacOS Sierra 10.12 or later* and another for *10.10 or 10.11*.

You can also see all available apps https://www.office.com/apps?auth=2&home=1 and use their online version with our without simplified ribbons. I never used them, so can't say about functionalities.

> computer is still not taking Mojave.

You can check compatibility for Mojave at https://support.apple.com/macos/mojave

For Sierra https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202

and for  High Sierra at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969

> apple said it might be a hardware issue since I was practicing scripts on the terminal last year.

That is very broad.